# Hide Command Window of .BAT file that Executes Another .EXE File

Tags: windows, command-line, copy, executable

This is a batch file in Windows.

Here is my .bat file

```
@echo off
copy "C:\Remoting.config-Training" "C:\Remoting.config"

"C:\ThirdParty.exe"
```

This works fine except the .bat file leaves the command window open the whole time the "ThirdParty" application is running.
I need the command window to close.

I would use the short-cut for the application but I must be able to run this copy command first (it actually changes which data base and server to use for the application).

The ThirdParty application does not allow the user to change the source of the db or the application server.

We're doing this to allow users to change from a test environment to the production environment.

Comment: Just found this and I think, it's really handy to hide a console window on call:
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hidden-start-runs-batch-files-silently-without-flickering-console/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using `start` works for me:

```
@echo off
copy "C:\Remoting.config-Training" "C:\Remoting.config"
start C:\ThirdParty.exe
```

EDIT: Ok, looking more closely, `start` seems to interpret the first parameter as the new window title if quoted. So, if you need to quote the path to your ThirdParty.exe you must supply a title string as well.

Examples:

```
:: Title not needed:
start C:\ThirdParty.exe

:: Title needed
start "Third Party App" "C:\Program Files\Vendor\ThirdParty.exe"
```

Comment: Now the Thirdparty app doesn't start and my command window stays open.

Comment: Yes, you're right. When I used this I did not quote the path to my application. Please have a look at my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks to Patrick Cuff for improving my answer. I'm still new to SO and did not realize until now that enough reputation would allow you to edit other people's posts...

Answer (score 32):

Create a `.vbs` file with this code:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "your_batch.bat",0,True
```

This `.vbs` will run `your_batch.bat` hidden.

Works fine for me.

Comment: For me it needed to start with `WScript.CreateObject`, and if you want to pass an argument through use: `WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "your_batch.bat """ & WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & """",0,True

Answer (score 11):

Using `start` works fine, unless you are using a scripting language. Fortunately, there's a way out for Python - just use `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`:

```
:: Title not needed:
start pythonw.exe application.py
```

In case you need quotes, do this:

```
:: Title needed
start "Great Python App" pythonw.exe "C:\Program Files\Vendor\App\application.py"
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
@echo off 
copy "C:\Remoting.config-Training" "C:\Remoting.config"
start C:\ThirdParty.exe
exit
```

Comment: Don't use the quotes around C:\ThirdParty.exe and this will work perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me. Without the exit command the terminal stayed aliva

Answer (score 9):

Great tip. It works with batch files that are running a java program also.

```
start javaw -classpath "%CP%" main.Main
```

Comment: This worked excellent for me however all I had to do was save `start javaw mainClass` into my `.bat` file and it was great!

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in trying my [silentbatch](http://www.taenarum.com/software/#silentbatch) program, which will run a `.bat`/`.cmd` script, suppress creation of the Command Prompt window entirely (so you won't see it appear and then disappear), and optionally log the output to a specified file.

Comment: Implemented similar solution. Looks like this question is good place to post it as additional answer. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use:

```
Start /d "the directory of the executable" /b "the name of the executable" "parameters of the executable" %1
```

If %1 is a file then it is passed to your executable. For example in `notepad.exe foo.txt` %1 is "foo.txt".

The `/b` parameter of the start command does this:

> Starts an application without opening a new Command Prompt window. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> handling is ignored unless the application enables <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> processing. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> to interrupt the application.

Which is exactly what we want.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't really found a good way to do that natively, so I just use a utility called [hstart](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html) which does it for me. If there's a neater way to do it, that would be nice.

Comment: HSTART is an excellent utility for replacement of the CMD window, plus it's meant to work with PowerShell and Ruby

Answer (score 3):

You can create a VBS script that will force the window to be hidden.

```vbs
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
obj = WshShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\McKesson\HRS
Distributed\SwE.bat""", 0)
set WshShell = Nothing
```

Then, rather than executing the batch file, execute the script.

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows API we can start new process, a console application, and hide its "black" window. This can be done at process creation and avoid showing "black" window at all.

In [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) function the `dwCreationFlags` parameter can have [CREATE_NO_WINDOW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/process-creation-flags) flag:

```
The process is a console application that is being run
without a console window. Therefore, the console handle
for the application is not set. This flag is ignored if
the application is not a console application
```

Here is a link to [hide-win32-console-window executable](https://github.com/AlexKordic/hide-win32-console-window/releases) using this method and [source code](https://github.com/AlexKordic/hide-win32-console-window/blob/master/batchscript_starter.cpp).

`hide-win32-console-window` is similar to [Jamesdlin's silentbatch program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15859075/70405).

There is open question: **what to do with program's output when its window does not exist?** What if exceptions happen? Not a good solution to throw away the output. `hide-win32-console-window` uses anonymous pipes to redirect program's output to file created in current directory.

### Usage

**batchscript_starter.exe** *full/path/to/application* [*arguments to pass on*]

### Example running python script

```
batchscript_starter.exe c:\Python27\python.exe -c "import time; print('prog start'); time.sleep(3.0); print('prog end');"
```

The output file is created in working directory named `python.2019-05-13-13-32-39.log` with output from the python command:

```
prog start
prog end
```

### Example running command

```
batchscript_starter.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C dir .
```

The output file is created in working directory named `cmd.2019-05-13-13-37-28.log` with output from CMD:

```
 Volume in drive Z is Storage
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-YYYY

 Directory of hide_console_project\hide-win32-console-window

2019-05-13  13:37    <DIR>          .
2019-05-13  13:37    <DIR>          ..
2019-05-13  04:41            17,274 batchscript_starter.cpp
2018-04-10  01:08            46,227 batchscript_starter.ico
2019-05-12  11:27             7,042 batchscript_starter.rc
2019-05-12  11:27             1,451 batchscript_starter.sln
2019-05-12  21:51             8,943 batchscript_starter.vcxproj
2019-05-12  21:51             1,664 batchscript_starter.vcxproj.filters
2019-05-13  03:38             1,736 batchscript_starter.vcxproj.user
2019-05-13  13:37                 0 cmd.2019-05-13-13-37-28.log
2019-05-13  04:34             1,518 LICENSE
2019-05-13  13:32                22 python.2019-05-13-13-32-39.log
2019-05-13  04:55                82 README.md
2019-05-13  04:44             1,562 Resource.h
2018-04-10  01:08            46,227 small.ico
2019-05-13  04:44               630 targetver.h
2019-05-13  04:57    <DIR>          x64
              14 File(s)        134,378 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  ???,???,692,992 bytes free
```

### Example shortcut for running .bat script

[image: Shortcut for starting windowless .bat file]

`Target` field:

```
C:\batchscript_starter.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:\start_wiki.bat
```

Directory specified in `Start in` field will hold output files.

Answer (score 2):

run it under a different user.  assuming this is a windows box, create a user account for scheduled tasks. run it as that user. The command prompt will only show for the user currently logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Compile the batch file to an executable using Batch2Exe http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e.
Use the "Invisible Window" option.

Comment: There wasn't enough information about this app to make me feel comfortable in trying it. FAQ. Demo, something more than a screen-shot of one tab.

Comment: Softpedia seems to have a good opinion about it: Bat To Exe Converter 1.6.0 - SOFTPEDIA "100% CLEAN" AWARD. Here is an alternative download link: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Batch-To-Exe-Converter.shtml

Comment: I used it. It worked on my one computer, but i moved the exe files to another and they don't work on it.

Answer (score 2):

To make the command window of a .bat file that executes a .exe file exit out as fast as possible, use the line `@start` before the file you're trying to execute. Here is an example:

```
(insert other code here)
@start executable.exe
(insert other code here)
```

You don't have to use other code with `@start executable.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

I used this to start a cmd file from C#:

```cs
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "myWorkingDirectory";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "myFileName.cmd";
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this one, the above does not work. I have tested in  Window server 2003.

```
@echo off 
copy "C:\Remoting.config-Training" "C:\Remoting.config"
Start /I "" "C:\ThirdParty.exe"
exit
```

Comment: What error did you get indicating the 'above' does not work? Maybe it is because you are using Windows Server?

Answer (score 1):

Adding **/min** to the start command hides the window completely for me on my **Windows 11 home edition**

```
start /min C:\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java -jar app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

So below vbscript will launch the cmd/bat file in hidden mode.

```
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)

'MsgBox(strFolder)

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & strFolder & "\a.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Now, only app window will be visible, not the cmd.exe window

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy work around for those who are fine with a dirty solution. Press win+tab, drag and drop the bat file to a new desktop and forget about it.

I occasionally will make a bat file that I'll rarely use, and it is kind of a drag to have to use tools to make the window hidden. This is no more complicated than it needs to be for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put it on the first line of your cmd script:

```
%1 start "" mshta vbscript:createobject("wscript.shell").run("""%~s0"" ::",0)(window.close)&&exit
```