# Stop invoking of new Shell/cmd prompt , python

Tags: python, shell, system, operating-system

i have a python script which should invoke a .exe file to get some result. That .exe file is invoking a new windows command prompt(shell) . i dont need any output from the .exe file.

i 'm using 
os.system('segwin.exe args') in my script where segwin is an executable.

now my question is : i need to stop invoking cmd prompt

kudos to all

sag

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507347/hide-command-window-of-bat-file-that-executes-another-exe-file) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
import subprocess
CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
args = [...]
subprocess.check_call(["segwin.exe"] + args, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

Note that `check_call` checks the return code of the launched subprocess and raises an exception if it's nonzero. If you don't want that, use `call` instead.

In general, avoid `os.system()` and use the `subprocess` module whenever possible. `os.system()` always starts a shell, which is nonportable unnecessary on most cases.

Comment: yes this is perfectly working 
but.,
segwin.exe is returning 1 on success which causes to raise CalledProcessError by check_all(). what should i do now :(

Comment: thankyou so much., i have used call() and the problem is solved...

u rockz man

sag

Comment: For completeness' sake I've added a note regarding `check_call`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually specific to Windows. Windows has decided that `segwin.exe` is a console-based application (uses the Console subsystem from the Windows C interface).

I know how to invoke an prompt for apps that don't necessarily want one, but not the reverse, you could try using [this](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html), or [this](http://www.adontec.com/starthidden_e.htm).