# Closing cmd after starting a Programm

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, cmd

How can I run this following Code with a `bat` file/ `vbs`-File and close the console instead of starting it?

```
cmd /c call %USERPROFILE%\myProgrammDir\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java.exe -jar %USERPROFILE%\myProgrammDir\myProgramm.jar
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/507347/894872

Answer (score 3):

I'd try changing `call` to `start`.

Like this:

```
cmd /c start %USERPROFILE%\myProgrammDir\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\java.exe -jar %USERPROFILE%\myProgrammDir\myProgramm.jar
```