# How to run minimized with (RunProgram)

Tags: batch-file, sfx, minimized

Is it possible to run the **installation.bat** minimized? And if so, how?

```
RunProgram="waitall:Installation.bat"
```

Comment: Hello, please be more specific with your problem. When you sat 'minimized' what do you mean? And think of adding more tags.

Comment: I create a SFX archive and it works but the Installation.but Window opens.. i want to hide it (start minimized or better not visible if it is possible).Dont know which command is needed or parameter -  somthing like /min or...?

Comment: Which SFX is running a batch file on extraction? Is it a WinZip SFX or a 7-Zip SFX or a WinRAR SFX? A batch file is a script file which needs a script interpreter. The script interpreter for batch files is the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` which is a Windows console application. For that reason a console window is opened by Windows as it is done usually for all console applications. But it is possible to run `cmd.exe` for execution of a batch file by another executable like Windows Script Host `wscript.exe` hidden without getting a console window displayed at all.

Comment: I would recommend to recode the batch file as Visual Basic script which is explicitly interpreted with `wscript.exe` after extraction of SFX archive to avoid getting a console window displayed at all. But I don't understand why it is such a big problem if a console window opens on extracting a self-extracting archive. Inform the user with first lines in batch file about what is done by the batch file and it should be no problem that a user gets a console window displayed, except your SFX is for malicious purposes on which the user should not know what is going on in background.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [link](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_hideconsole.php) will help you.
Or this answer from another question: [Hide Command Window of .BAT file that Executes Another .EXE File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507347/hide-command-window-of-bat-file-that-executes-another-exe-file)

Comment: No thx. The SFX Archive i create is a .exe file. I doubleklick this .exe ant then automatically the Installation.bat starts - it opens (in) a window. it is all fine but i only want is, that the windows when opens, do this minimized in Taskbar - or when possible not visible - just like i silent installation. hope you know what i mean.